# How to run an indefinite loop in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polling, rails-activejob

I'm trying to short poll an external API which doesn't support websockets, so I need to constantly make API requests every few seconds or maybe multiple times per second.

I also need to be in control of calling the next poll run. For example I wouldn’t want to run the poll again while my request is pending or I might want to increase the timeout if I get a 500 error.

Currently, considering doing this in a separate node process and only notify the rails server when there's new data. But I'd rather just do everything in the rails codebase.

I don't think ActiveJobs is built for this purpose but I could be wrong. I think what I really need is a separate entry point in the rails app repository that loads all the models but doesn't start the server and then write the loop for short polling, But not sure if that's best practice or trivial to do with rails.

So should I proceed with the node approach or is there an easy Rails solution I'm missing? Any suggestion or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you want an Observer. Standard lib [has one](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/stdlibs/observer/Observable.html). There may exist more Rails tailored solutions.

Comment: Did you consider pushing new data instead of pulling and looking for new data?

Comment: I'd probably write a small stand-alone service which wraps those continuous API calls and provides some kind of change stream for its clients (i.e. for your app). That service doesn't even have to be Ruby.

Comment: @spickermann it’s an external API.

Comment: Is the external APIs owner okay with you sending up to multiple requests to their API per second? Are rate limits in place?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

It help you run a method or a rake task with crontab.

```
# schedule.rb
every 1.minute do
  runner "YourClass.your_method"
end

every 1.minute do
  rake "polling:task"
end
```

After finish `schedule.rb` file, you'll need to execute `whenever --update-crontab` in you deploy pipiline in order to update crontab.

Comment: The shortest interval in cron is 1 minute which can't handle _"every few seconds or maybe multiple times per second"_. Each task of course _could_ poll the API multiple times for a total of 1 minute but then you have to very carefully time or synchronize adjacent jobs in order to not have overlap issues.

Comment: Yeah if the minimum interval is 1 minute it’s not suitable. I also added a note about how I have to control the next run of the poll and sometimes change the timeout for the next run.